# Android 13 High rate java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in background

Tags: android, concurrentmodificationexception

```
Exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException:
  at java.util.WeakHashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry (WeakHashMap.java:807)
  at java.util.WeakHashMap$KeyIterator.next (WeakHashMap.java:840)
  at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray (AbstractCollection.java:144)
  at java.util.ArrayList.<init> (ArrayList.java:191)
  at android.app.PropertyInvalidatedCache.getActiveCaches (PropertyInvalidatedCache.java:1413)
  at android.app.PropertyInvalidatedCache.onTrimMemory (PropertyInvalidatedCache.java:1615)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleTrimMemory (ActivityThread.java:6361)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleTrimMemory
  at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.lambda$scheduleTrimMemory$0 (ActivityThread.java:1746)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.accept
  at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke (PooledLambdaImpl.java:281)
  at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke (PooledLambdaImpl.java:204)
  at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run (OmniFunction.java:97)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7884)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

speical point in
`at android.app.PropertyInvalidatedCache.onTrimMemory (PropertyInvalidatedCache.java:1615)` when the onTrimMemory time,for itertor the cache activities.

it only found in the android 13 system.